# How do I stop the output of my Python program after a specific length of time so I can start a new process?

Tags: python, streaming

I'm using tweepy to scrape tweets and spit out the letters in the console line by line. However, I'd like to start a new process after I've printed out a specific number of characters or after a length of time.

Here's what I tried.

```
class Listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data (self, data):
        tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","Liksource')[0]
        for letter in tweet:
            number = ord(letter)
            print (letter)
        if len(sys.stdout) == 50:
            print "Hello world!"
```

I want this to print "Hello World!" just to demonstrate I can start a new thing, but also would like to stop the streaming of data. I tried using a `break` and it wouldn't let me.

Comment: What is `StreamListener`? Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's imported from the tweepy library. You can see the documentation for it here: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html?highlight=StreamListener